# Google Calender in android application

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I want to reproduce google calender in my application which shows all events in calender, After clicking on date, details of Even on that date should be displayed and if there is no event then option to add event must be given.

My question is whether google(android) provide any in build widgets which is capable of showing events, Currently I am using CalenderView which shows only dates and there is no way to show events in it.

if there is any material on this problem please let me know. I know GoogleCalender v3 api and how to retrieve data from there my main problem is how to show events in calender.